# RSA given 30% MSB of p and 30%MSB of q

Tags: rsa, factoring

is factoring RSA given 30% MSB of p  and 30%MSB of q  possible in polynomial time?

Notice that it is known that given 50%  MSB of p or q it is doable in polynomial time using Coppersmith's theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the reference given in the other answer is 18 years old, as well as being erroneous w.r.t. division as pointed out by @fgrieu, I did some digging around for more recent results/updates on Coppersmith's method.

*Disclaimer:* These results were unknown to me, but probably not to the experts.

There are tutorial-style notes by Henninger [2020 or newer judging from references], a paper by Cohn and Henninger [2013] where applications to cryptography beyond just RSA factoring are also discussed. This includes Guruswami-Sudan list decoding, which is relevant to code-based cryptography schemes, such as McEliece.

Howgrave-Graham and May apparently have the newest updated proofs on Coppersmith's method. The punchline is that indeed  knowing 50% of the bits is the limit to which the method can be used to deduce polynomial time factoring of a well chosen RSA modulus.

In a set of notes from May, available [here](https://www.cits.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/imperia/md/content/may/paper/intro_to_coppersmiths_method.pdf) [2019+], other applications including the two listed below are also described:

- Polynomial time attacks for RSA secret keys $d$ with a small Chinese Remainder representation, i.e. $d_p = d \pmod{p-1}$ and $d_q = d \pmod{q - 1}$ are both
  small. This is a question with practical significance, since for performance reasons almost all real-world RSA implementations compute the RSA decryption
  function using CRT-exponents $(d_p, d_q)$. Then a recent result due to Takayasu, Lu and Peng says that if $\max(d_p,d_q)\leq N^{0.122}$ the factorization of $N$ can be found in time $O(\log^{6+\epsilon} N)$ for any $\epsilon > 0.$
- Hidden number problem (see Theorem 1.16).

Answer (score 1):

No, knowing the MSB of p you could calculate the MSB of q dividing it by n, so knowing MSB of p AND q is redundant.

~50% with coppersmith is the best u can do (for now...)

https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2006/cacr2006-16.pdf

section 6.1

Comment: this may well be true but please edit your answer with references [if any] that 50% is the best with Coppersmith's method. And your first paragraph is unclear [at least to me]

Comment: The first sentence of the answer still proposes a division with dividend and divisors inverted.